# How to edit Plymouth theme to fit the screen

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

So, I have [this Plymouth theme](https://github.com/1deterministic/Plymouth-Progress-Bar) that I want to edit. I have tried to edit it so that the top of the logo PNG is aligned with the top edge of the screen, and that the progress bar is aligned with the bottom edge of the screen and takes up the width of the screen, similar to the boot-up screen from Windows 9x. However, when I attempted to modify the theme, the progress bar and logo seemed to have some sort of unused space border instead of being aligned exactly with the edges of the screen. I tried searching for how to fix the alignment and couldn't find any documentation other than a Reddit thread for Fedora which said to add `DeviceScale=2` to `/etc/plymouth/plymouthd.conf`, but this file is unused on Ubuntu according to [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth).

Is there any way to fix the alignment for Ubuntu?